# How to only update input of p:selectOneMenu, not the suggestion panel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm using primefaces 5.3 and i have a page which has p:selectOneMenu as below:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="addressCountry" value="#{myBean.address.country}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.countries}" var="country" 
                 itemValue="#{country.code}" itemLabel="#{country.name}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

This is a combobox that allow users to select their country. It show all countries around the world (250 countries) so it lead to performance problem.

My page have several tabView and each of them has several comboboxes like this, when i switch tab and update whole tabView, all those comboboxes will be renderred again and it increase payload a lot.

I know with SelectOneMenu, Primefaces divide it into two parts: the input and the panel to hold all selectable options. When i update this component by *id* (**update=":#{p:component('addressCountry')}"**), Primefaces will render both parts, even the panel just static contents and no need to be rendered again for every request.

I've try to update by css selector (just select the input) but it also not work.

Can we only update the input, exclude the panel when we need?

Anybody can help me?
Thanks alot

Comment: can't you just use a different component like the autocomplete? with these you can just supply data as needed?

Comment: Primefaces 6.1.2 supports lazy selectOneMenu, but you'd need to pay for that, because it will take some time until they'll release the next community version. You could write your own component, here's the code: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/d4f2148981d8bbdb2ef1eb0dc060c42a17074989. Another option would be to use the plain jsf h:selectOneMenu, which is faster.

Comment: @Lastresort: You can always download the source and use that

Comment: thanks @lastresort . i will try.

Comment: hi @Fritz , my customer does not want to use autocomplete here.